# How to move the value in a larger-typed register into a smaller-typed destination?

Tags: pointers, assembly, type-conversion, masm, cpu-registers

For example, I want to move a DWORD value in a register into a memory location typed WORD, but am getting errors:

```
mov [arr + eax*TYPE arr], edx ; error: operands must be same size
```

the [] brackets dereference to an array element of type WORD.

I've tried doing this as well:

```
    mov dx, edx ; error: operands must be same size.     
    mov [arr + eax*TYPE arr], dx
```

Also no luck trying to use PTR:

```
mov dx, WORD PTR edx ; error: invalid use of register
```

OR

```
 mov WORD PTR [arr + eax*TYPE arr], edx ; error: invalid use of register
```

OR

```
mov [arr + eax*TYPE arr], WORD PTR edx ; error: invalid use of register
```

Solution? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You cannot put a gallon of water into a 1/2 gallon jug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register `DX` is actually the lowest 16 bit of the 32 bit register `EDX`. You **don't** need to `mov dx, edx` because `DX` is already there. So you simply need to store DX in the word sized variable:

```
mov  [word_variable], dx
```

Of course the highest 16 bit of edx will be lost in such a transfer.